# После клонирования репозитория файлы на master/originals отличаются от файлов на других ветках

Tags: git, github, webstorm

Клонирую с мастер ветки себе на  локальный репозитоий проект.. Изначально в локальном не моя личная(локальная) ветка отображается, а мастер ветка.. там все актуальные файлы.. перехожу на свою.. и там видна лишь часть файлов. Fetch  не помогает.. merge c мастером не доступен в списке выбора веток
Подскажите в чём может быть проблема. Спасибо

Comment: Непонятно о какой проблеме речь.

Answer (score 0):

те у кого будет похожая проблема:перед клонированием проекта был мёрдж
моей локальной ветки и ветки мастера,из-за выбранного merge theirs были сохранены только часть изменений.. после чего моя локальная ветка стала по статусу такой же как мастер,но с меньшим количеством файлов(со всеми проблемами которые я описал в вопросе).Решение:перейти на ветку мастер.. и создать новую ветку. .в ней будут все файлы соответствующие мастер ветке.. Старые локальные ветки,после этого можно снести.